# Start gnome-terminal with predefined history

Tags: bash, bash-history

I would like to start a Gnome terminal window with a predefined history file.

I tried:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "history -c; history -r ~/test.hist; exec bash"'
```

but it still uses the standard history file: `~/.bash_history`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history file is set using the `HISTFILE` variable. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1):

```
HISTFILE
      The name of the file in which  command  history  is  saved  (see
      HISTORY  below).   The  default  value  is  ~/.bash_history.  If
      unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.
```

You can try:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "export HISTFILE=~/test.hist; exec bash"'
```